# Code Igniter error?

Tags: php, codeigniter, syntax-error

Can somebody help me, I am new in CI, and I don't know what do I do wrong.

I have this kind of **controller**

main

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class main extends CI_Controller {
 public function index() {
     $this->home();
 }

 public function home() {
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->model("get_db");
    $data['results']=$this->get_db->getAll();
    $this->load->view("view_home", $data);
 }
}
```

And the model `get_db` like this

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
    class get_db extends CI_Model {
        public function getAll() {
        $query=$this->db->query("SELECT * from tekstovi");
        return $query->result();
    }
}
```

I got this strange error like this

```
**A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined property: main::$db
Filename: core/Model.php
Line Number: 51**
```

Any idea what to correct?

Comment: Class names must have the first letter capitalized with the rest of the name lowercase. Make sure your class extends the base Model class. http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/models.html same for controllers: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html

Comment: Changed that still same error

Comment: remove word "public" from your model function/functions

Comment: tried to load database class and capitalized names for modeles and controllers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add __construct() to your controller and model. Try the following.

Your controller

```
class main extends CI_Controller 
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

public function index() 
{
     $this->home();
}

public function home() 
{
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->model("get_db");
    $data['results']=$this->get_db->getAll();
    $this->load->view("view_home", $data);
   }

 }
```

Your model.

```
class Get_db extends CI_Model
{
    function __construct()
    {
    parent::__construct();

    }

    // here is your code
    public function getAll() {
        $query=$this->db->query("SELECT * from tekstovi");
        return $query->result();
    }
}
```

Comment: Now this kind of error  Unable to load the requested file: helpers/_helper.php

Answer (score 1):

```
// Location: application/controllers/main.php
class Main extends CI_Controller {

    public function index() { 

        $this->home();

    }

    public function home() { 

        $this->load->model('home_model');

        $data['results'] = $this->home_model->getAll();

        $this->load->view("view_home", $data);

    }
}

// Location: application/models/home_model.php
class Home_model extends CI_Model {

public function getAll() {

        $query=$this->db->query("SELECT * from tekstovi");

        return $query->result();

    }

}
```

I think it would be very helpful for you if you take a look at [CodeIgniter's User Guide](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/index.html).

**Edit:** If you are doing these things right and you still have problem, please make sure that core files are not modified. If they are, you can reinstall the application (download and update files) and everything should works.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @nevermind, you need to correct the naming of your classes.

> Class names must have the first letter capitalized with the rest of
>   the name lowercase. Make sure your class extends the base Model class.
>
> The file name will be a lower case version of your class name.

The next problem I see is that you have no constructor in your model. Add the following code to your model.

```
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
}
```

There is no problem with your model's functions being `public`.